# How to customize / add sections to the LiveCharts legend?

Tags: c#, wpf, legend, livecharts

I use LiveCharts to display some measurements in a UserControl of an MVVM WPF app.
I want to compare my recent measurements with a baseline. Typically, the baseline is constant respectively a horizontal line parallel to the x-axis, therefore I added a *SectionsCollection* containing a *new AxisSection* to my ViewModel.
Subsequently, I bound my *SectionsCollection* to the *Sections* property of my y-axis in my View.
It is displayed properly and simultaneously my recent measurements are displayed as a *Series*.

Unfortunately the default legend does not display the *Sections*, just the *Series* of measurements. That's why I overwrite the default legend in my LiveChartsView.xaml with my local:LegendView

```
<UserControl x:Class="<ViewNamespace>.LiveChartsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:<ViewNamespace>"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:<ViewModelNamespace>
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:LiveChartsViewModel}"
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
        <vmhelper:ContinuousMeasurementVmConverter x:Key="ContinuousMeasurementVmConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border BorderThickness="10">
        <Grid>
            <lvc:CartesianChart Series="Series="{Binding ContinuousMeasurements, Converter={StaticResource ContinuousMeasurementVmConverter}}" LegendLocation="Right" >
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Response Time [ms]" MinValue="0"/>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                    <lvc:Axis Title="Measurement Date" Labels="{Binding Labels}" LabelsRotation="45">
                        <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                            <lvc:Separator Step="1" />
                        </lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    </lvc:Axis>                    
                </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:CartesianChart.ChartLegend>
                    <local:LegendView></local:LegendView>
                </lvc:CartesianChart.ChartLegend>                
            </lvc:CartesianChart>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

My LiveChartsViewModel.cs is a basic ViewModel with the two collections as properties:

```
public class LiveChartsViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MeasurementViewModel> _continuousMeasurements;

        public ObservableCollection<MeasurementViewModel> ContinuousMeasurements
        {
            get => _continuousMeasurements;
            set
            {
                _continuousMeasurements = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContinuousMeasurements));
            }
        }
}
public LiveChartsViewModel()
{
PopulateContinuousMeasurements();
}
}
```

My LegendView.xaml looks like the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="<LegendViewNamespace>"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="<ViewNamespace>"
             xmlns:vm="<ViewModelNamespace>"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:LegendView}">
    <ListView BorderThickness="0">        
        <ListViewItem>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContinuousMeasurements}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Title"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                               Width="15" Height="15"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="4 0" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>    
</UserControl>
```

And my code-behind LegendView.xaml.cs

```
namespace <LegendViewNamespace>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for LegendView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LegendView : UserControl, IChartLegend
    {
        public LegendView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new LiveChartsViewModel();
        }

        private List<SeriesViewModel> _series;

        public List<SeriesViewModel> Series
        {
            get { 
                return _series; }
            set
            {
                _series = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Series));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out, how I must adapt any of my files to display the sections in my legend, too. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: There are many solutions. For example you could add a seconds ListView to your `LegendView`, which binds to a your section items.

Comment: You should consider to replace the `ItemsControl` with a `ListView` to get a scroll bar.

Comment: Hi @BionicCode,
I replaced the `ItemsControl` with the ListView and added a second one bound to my `LegendView` Code-behind as you suggested.
As soon as my `LiveChartsViewModel` populates my `SeriesCollection`, the `Series` property of my `LegendView` is also set. I must register a DependencyProperty to achieve the same effect for my `SectionsCollection` respectively `Sections`, right?

Comment: If you want to bind the SeriesCollection to the ListView, then you don't need a DependencyProperty. Just use a ObservableCollection. Also notice that in an MVVM context you shouldn't create our handle SerieCollection in the view model. SeriesCollection extends UIElement and is an element of the view. You should define the SeriesCollection in XAML, or in case the number of series are not known in advance, you should create the series using a IValueComverter.

Comment: Thank you very much @BionicCode!
I didn't see the forest for the trees...